# Using DAO calls inside another DAO - DAO dependency

Tags: java, dependencies, dao

I have a basic question.

I have been creating DAO with separation of concern. Each DAO concentrates on the BusinessObject in context. My question is on using one DAO method inside another DAO. I have assumed that is wrong but do not have enough data support.

Here is the situation.

```
EmpDAO:
   getEmp(empId)
   getEmps(deptId)
   getEmps(deptName)
```

What are the issues of having the below implementation

```
getEmps(deptName):
    // Assume this is cached and there is no question of two N/w calls and having any gain by joins
    DeptDAO.getId(deptName)
    getEmps(deptId)
```

What can go wrong with using DeptDAO inside EmpDAO? Or What are the points because of which I should not have a DAO call inside another DAO.

Regards
Amod

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: It looks like phylosophy rather than technology (one would say "design pattern" ;). As far as I'm concerned, I can tell that for one given DAO I never hesitate to use other(s) DAO(s) if it allows to avoid duplicate code and if it simplifies pieces of code.

Comment: pls do not go by the code structure these are templates.

Answer (score 3):

Calling DAO inside another DAO is discouraged. Why doesn't your service do the work ? A service method like:

```
public void combinedServiceWork(String deptName) {
    long deptId = DeptDAO.getId(deptName);
    EmpDAO.getEmps(deptId);
}
```

And get rid of `getEmps(deptName)` in `EmpDAO`;

Comment: I can do this but I do not want to repeat same code in different service methods or service classes. Anyways, the question is not about what is the alternative. The question is, is there a strong reason (or any reason) to not do it. I just want to be sure we are not being sheep here :) If it is discouraged, why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get your information.  Can you provide a citation that told you this was so heinous an error?  It could be a way to hand code one-to-many relationships.

I have more problem with making these static.

Comment: Why do you assume he's making static calls? Maybe he just doesn't respect conventions and uses member names starting with a capital letter.